# Wording not translated on Portuguese site

Tags: bug, tradução, internacionalização, newsletter

I believe the translation didn't make it on the Portuguese stackoverflow site.

[image]

Comment: Duplicata parcial de http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/968/falha-de-tradu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-layout-no-an%C3%BAncio-da-newsletter